# can you store non-volatile variable using code instead of an .ini file

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing automation software that will be used on multiple manufacturing rigs that are numbered sequentially 1,2,3,4,5,... I want to reference and log the serial number of these rigs during the automation process. Typically I would place an .ini file on each rig with it's unique serial number, but since I'm only storing a single variable, it seems like a waste to deal with .ini files.

Is there a way to assign and store the rig serial number as a non-volatile variable in my code?

Comment: If you are asking if there is a way to update your .exe file at runtime, I believe the answer is no. If you want to store data, you will need to store it in a separate file of some sort (perhaps the Registry).

Comment: If it's a part of the machine name, you could easily parse it from that.  E.g., `MFGRIG01`

Comment: `My.Settings` would probably do nicely.  Easy to get to, easy to save/load etc

Comment: ps2goat and Plutonix... both of these suggestions will solve my problem. Thanks!